# Oracle dynamic partition in join

Tags: sql, oracle

I did a query to find a list of products, with their details ( we have a parent product that is splitted in several details products), and a table where we store the history of our price changes on this product.

I've got the following query that is working well on my oracle database:

```
SELECT ref, size, is_promotion, original_price, histo_npx as "current_price" , histo_apx as "old_price"
from product
    left join product_details on product_ref = ref
    left join (select product_ref, histo_npx, histo_dex, histo_apx,
                    rank() over (partition by price.product_ref order by histo_dex DESC) modif_rank
               from price
               where histo_npx is not null
                 and price.product_ref = 'MY_REF'
                 and price.product_size = 'MY_SIZE'
               order by price.histo_dex, price.product_ref) on product_ref = ref
where (modif_rank = 1 or modif_rank is null)
  and ref = 'MY_REF'
  and size = 'MY_SIZE'
```

But I need to make it dynamically without forcing values of MY_REF and MY_SIZE.
When I remove the where in my subquery and query,  it is of course not good as I have all the history for the oldest product of my database, so I need to restrain my subquery if I remove the `and ref = 'MY_REF' and size = 'MY_SIZE'` of my global query.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put query inside view or subquery and dynamically add where filters for `ref = 'MY_REF' and size = 'MY_SIZE'` in outer query
You may use such query:

```
SELECT ref, size, is_promotion, original_price, histo_npx as "current_price" , histo_apx as "old_price"
from product
    left join product_details on product_ref = ref
    left join (select product_ref,product_size, histo_npx, histo_dex, histo_apx,
                    rank() over (partition by price.product_ref, price.product_size order by histo_dex DESC) modif_rank
               from price
               where histo_npx is not null) on product_ref = ref and product_size = size
where (modif_rank = 1 or modif_rank is null)
```

I removed

```
                 and price.product_ref = 'MY_REF'
                 and price.product_size = 'MY_SIZE'
  and ref = 'MY_REF'
  and size = 'MY_SIZE'
```

filters.
Also add `price.product_size` to rank() partition by clause and `product_size=size` to join condition.

Comment: Damn I was almost good, I did forgot the field in the partition... good job!